# Rails 4 attr_readonly on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, readonly

I want to make an attribute read only for each record after the first update, is there a way to do this in Rails 4 using attr_readonly? Or another method?

It has to do with Transaction security...

Comment: After the first update or on create?

Comment: only after the first update. I want that attribute to create (as nil) and freeze after the first update.

Comment: You should probably implement this in your controller and delete that parameter from any updates you apply.

Comment: This seems like business logic specific to a model. It shouldn't go in the controller.

Comment: Yes it is in the model, not controller

Comment: With Rails 4 attr_readonly won't work on instances, otherwise I would include that line within the transaction block to make sure the attribute of interest can't be touched again afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr_readonly` is a class method, so it would "freeze" the attribute on all instances of the model, whether they've been updated or not.

The sanest way to do what you want, I think, would be to add a `some_attribute_is_frozen` boolean attribute to your model, and then set it to `true` in a `before_update` callback. Then you can have a validation that will only run if `some_attribute_is_frozen?` is `true`, and which will fail if the "frozen" attribute has changed.

Something like this (for the sake of an example I've arbitrarily chosen "Customer" as the name of the model and `address` as the name of the attribute you want to "freeze"):

```
# $ rails generate migration AddAddressIsFrozenToCustomers
# => db/migrate/2014XXXX_add_address_is_frozen_to_customers.rb
class AddAddressIsFrozenToCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :customers, :address_is_frozen, :boolean,
      null: false, default: false
  end
end
```

```
# app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :mark_address_as_frozen  
  validate :frozen_address_cannot_be_changed, if: :address_is_frozen?

  # ...snip...

  private
  def mark_address_as_frozen
    self.address_is_frozen = true
  end

  def frozen_address_cannot_be_changed
    return unless address_changed?
    errors.add :address, "is frozen and cannot be changed"
  end
end
```

Since [the `before_update` callback runs after validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks), the very first time the record is updated, `address_is_frozen?` will return `false` and the validation will be skipped. On the next update, though, `address_is_frozen?` will return `true` and so the validation will run, and if `address` has changed the validation will fail with a useful error message.

I hope that's helpful!

Comment: Close enough, currently I'm setting a similar attribute to TRUE within a Transaction block on update, along with altering other parameters, but using before_update validation is good for me to prevent subsequent Users from trying to modify the same record... I hope. I guess in Postgres there's no way to freeze records on Update too. This will be fine.